# Buck converter inductor ripple current percentage

Tags: power-supply, switch-mode-power-supply, buck

I am designing a buck converter using [LMR36015](https://www.ti.com/lit/ds/symlink/lmr36015.pdf?ts=1694618694432&ref_url=https%253A%252F%252Fwww.google.com%252F) (Texas Instrument). The specifications are:

- Input voltage: 24V (+/-10%) = 21.6-26.4V
- Output voltage: 3.3V
- Output current: 0.4A
- Fsw = 1MHz

This leads to a on-time of 125ns.
If I calculate the inductance value using the rule of thumb of 40% ripple current ratio, I find a value of 18µH.
I decided to check the result on the TI software Webench and I was surprised to find a much lower inductance value of 2.2µH with an inductor ripple current percentage of 257% (although there is an option to choose the inductor ripple up to 200%)

[image]

[image]

I dug into the datasheet and found the note that the ripple current percentage must be higher for output current lower than the maximum current capacity of the IC.

[image]

On Webench, when increasing the output current closer to the IC current capability, the ripple current ratio approaches 40%. When decreasing the output current, it increases a lot (>250%).

My questions are:

- Why when operating at low output current (in comparison to the IC current limit), the ripple current ratio increases? Is it specific to this TI controller?
- How can I choose a ripple current ratio when operating in DCM? I believe the software purposely reduces the inductance value to operate in DCM.
- Is it correct to state that a 200% ripple current ratio is the transition point from CCM to DCM (BCM)? Does it mean that a ripple current ratio of >200% means going further in DCM?

Thank you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> *I decided to check the result on the TI software Webench and I was
> surprised to find a much lower inductance value of 2.2µH*

That value seems in the right ball-park for the boundary condition: -

- Your power output requirement is 3.3 volts at 0.4 amps (\$I_{AV}\$); that's 1.32 watts
- Your switching frequency of 1 MHz implies an energy transfer of 1.32 μJ per cycle
- Energy \$=\frac{1}{2}\cdot LI_{PK}^2\$ and, at the boundary we know that \$I_{PK}\$ will be twice \$I_{AV}\$
- So, L will be 4.125 μH

> *On Webench, when increasing the output current closer to the IC
> current capability, the ripple current ratio approaches 40%. When
> decreasing the output current, it increases a lot (>250%).*

and

> *Why when operating at low output current (in comparison to the IC
> current limit), the ripple current ratio increases? Is it specific to
> this TI controller?*

On high load currents, the converter will be running in CCM and this means that the ratio of ripple (pk-to-pk) to average current decreases. At the boundary condition the ripple current has to be twice the average current hence the ratio is 200%. As the converter drops into DCM ripple increases more. It naturally happens this way.

> *How can I choose a ripple current ratio when operating in DCM?*

You are letting the tail wag the dog it seems; do the math on energy transfer at the boundary condition and you end up with a more suitable candidate inductor.

> *Is it correct to state that a 200% ripple current ratio is the
> transition point from CCM to DCM (BCM)? Does it mean that a ripple
> current ratio of >200% means going further in DCM?*

Yes and yes.

Comment: Thank you for the explanation.